# Freeze Columns FROM Row Group during Horizontal Scroll in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a `ssrs` Report. It have 15 `columns`. First 4 `columns` are Region, district, Office, week ( These are the part of Row Groups). The `report` is toggled based on these `columns`. Now my requirement is, I need to Freeze these `columns` in the `report` while `scrolling` other columns horizontally. I have tried with setting `Fixed data true` property etc... which doesn't worked out.

Could anyone help me to find the solution? thanks for the help

Comment: So you just want to retain the column headers and thats it? Im confused about what you are asking here.

Comment: Have you set `KeepWithgroup` to **After**?

Comment: @BWoods. Exactly. I need first four columns (Region, District, Office, Week) to be static and all other columns scrollable.

Comment: @HannoverFist  No I dont aware about that option. What will it do?. could you elaborate?